# Index of a button inside a Repeater

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatable, repeater

I have implemented a repeater with buttons in each row. On the click of the button I need to find the index of the row in which the button was clicked using jquery. I have also implemented the jquery datatable to display the data. 
My table id is ADMIN.

This is my jquery...

```
$('#ADMIN TR:gt(0)').each(function (){})
```

This returns three rows such as tr.even, tr.odd....

Also my button Class is Save I was able to obtain the indices using the following jquery.. but I find it difficult to separate out this index and perform an action

```
$('.Save').closest('tr').each(function () {
    var a= $(this).index();
```

I tried to access the index but it was of no use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Handle grabbing the index on the actual click of the button:

```
$('.Save').click(function () {
    var index = $(this).closest("tr").index();
});
```